# Excel fields must add up to 100% and if not spread field values evenly if no entry made

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 fields that must equal 100%.

```
A | B
-------
1 | 20%
2 | 20%
3 | 20%
4 | 20%
5 | 20%
-------
Total = 100%
```

If the user clicks B2 and changes the 20% to 25% it should evenly disperse the remaining fields to equal 100% so it would end up like this:

```
A | B
-------
1 | 17.5%
2 | 30%
3 | 17.5%
4 | 17.5%
5 | 17.5%
-------
Total = 100%
```

I found a solution on an excel forum and they show to use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim NewValue As Double
Dim ControlRange As Range
Dim Item As Range
Set ControlRange = Range("A1:A4")

If Not Intersect(ControlRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
    'The change occured in one of the cells we want to control

    NewValue = (1 - Target.Value) / 3
    For Each Item In ControlRange
        If Not Item.Address = Target.Address Then ' Don't change the cell that was changed
            Item.Value = NewValue
        End If
    Next
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Set ControlRange = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

and I would assume that I would only have to alter these lines:

`Set ControlRange = Range("A1:A4")` and `NewValue = (1 - Target.Value) / 3`

Here is the kicker though.  I did Alt+F11, insert module, and pasted that in.  Then I exited to the doc, and did Alt+F8 to view macros and it doesn't show up.

I read that it won't show up if "private" is in the code but I removed and it still doesn't show.

How do I make this code apply to a document?  I nearly have the answer but can't find how to make it actually trigger.

**EDIT:**
The advice given below helped to make the sub routine actually work which is great news.  However, I need help with what the function is to actually accomplish.

What works is that if I enter a number into a field, it evenly disperses the % between the remaining fields.  But the goal is that if you do enter a value manually, it KEEPS that value untouched, and any remaining fields would evenly disperse.  Then if you entered into a second field, it keeps the first and second fields untouched.  Changing a third field would keep all 3 of those fields the same. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` macros should go in the code module for the worksheet where you want to capture the event, not in a regular module.

Comment: Usually after Alt-F11, I would "insert > module".  With your advice, I clicked "view > code" from the menu.  I pasted my code in, chose "file > close and return to microsoft excel" and the cells calculated everything and started working perfect.  But the function isn't performing as I hoped.  I will make an edit above in my original post.

Comment: I will count your answer as correct because you helped solve "how to make the code apply".  I will try to figure out the equation for the second part of the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of flag on each cell in the range, so that your code can tell the difference between a manually-entered value and one which was set via the Worksheet_Change handler.

Maybe use a specific background of cell color for example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const FLAG_COLR As Long = vbRed

    Dim ControlRange As Range, tot
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rngCalc As Range
    Set ControlRange = Me.Range("B1:B5")

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(ControlRange, Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        rng.Font.Color = FLAG_COLR
        'find the range to which the calculation should be applied,
        '  and sum the entered values
        tot = 0
        For Each c In ControlRange.Cells
            If c.Font.Color <> FLAG_COLR Then
                If rngCalc Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngCalc = c
                Else
                    Set rngCalc = Application.Union(c, rngCalc)
                End If
            Else
                tot = tot + c.Value
            End If
        Next c

        If Not rngCalc Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            rngCalc.Value = (100 - tot) / rngCalc.Cells.Count
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```